# regular expression for numbers without their end character that connect to them

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I need regular expression for numbers that can be negative, with commas or decimal.

For examples: 12 +12 -12.0  -12,345.5466  +12,345,678,678  0.154

But not pass: "500." or "500,".
I want that 500 will return as a number without the point or the comma that connect to the number.

The regular expression that I wrote is:

> `[-+]?((0|([1-9](\d*|\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*)))(\.\d*[0-9])?)(?!\S)`

It is work at the correct numbers (like the examples), but It don't work for the '500,' or '500.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to match `500` in `500.` and `500,`, you should bear in mind that `(?!\S)` requires a whitespace or end of string immediately to the right.

You may fix the problem with

```php
[-+]?(?:0|[1-9](?:\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|\d*))(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rLhPkt/1), and note that this can be further enhanced depending on what contexts you need to exclude.

I replaced `(?!\S)` with `(?!\d)` at the end to fail the match if there is a digit, not any non-whitespace char, immediately on the right.

Note also that I removed unnecessary groups and converted all capturing groups to non-capturing.

Also, pay attention to the `(?:,\d{3})*|\d*)` group, where I swapped the alternatives since the first one is more specific and should go first.

*Details*

- `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `(?:0|[1-9](?:\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|\d*))` - `0` or

  - `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
  - `(?:\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|\d*)` - either

    - `\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*` - zero, one or two digits, and then zero or more occurrences of a comma and three digits
    - `|` - or
    - `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thank you very mach. I have one more question. if I want that but not to sepeatae % from the number, like 500% ?

Comment: @lirongr1996 It [already handles](https://regex101.com/r/rLhPkt/2) `500%`. Only `500` is matched.

Comment: I understand. Do you konw how the expression like  '12,34.54' or '0.15,4' or '5,6+78' will not pass ?

Comment: @lirongr1996 Because these are not correct numbers. `12,34.54` is `12` and `34.54`.  `0.15,4` is a `0.15` and `4`. And  `5,6+78` contains three matches.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant. How those expression not pass at all ? It consider the expression as whole and not dismantled, because there is no space.

Comment: @lirongr1996 I do not understand what you mean by "not pass". Regex either matches a string or not. The regex I shared matches exactly as I explained. If you need specific behavior, please explain what you expect to obtain for each string.

Comment: @lirongr1996 Did my answer resolve your original issue? What is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, it resolve the original issue perfect. I want those expression not match at all because they are not correct numbers. for example '12,34.54' not match because there isn't 3 digit after the comma, or '5,6+78' not match because there is + in the middle, or if there is '-+1' also not match.   Thank you very very mach for your help

Comment: @lirongr1996 I think I understood: these strings you posted are standalone strings, and not space separated. You need a pattern like `^[-+]?(?:0|[1-9](?:\d{0,2}(?:,(?:\d{3})*)*|\d*))(?:\.\d*)?$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rLhPkt/3).

Comment: No, thank you so mach for your help